# WPF main window invisible when maximised second screen on startup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

Our application main window is invisible on startup if the previous instance main window was maximised on a second monitor. If I hover over the task bar the window preview is blank

[image]

I then need to click several times on the task bar icon, firstly to minimise the window and then to display it albeit maximised on the second monitor.

If the previous instance was closed from monitor 1 or the main window was not maximised then on startup it displays as expected.

I have tried to implement this code from the OnStartup method after lengthy reading around similar issues but the behaviour remains unchanged.

```
 if (this.MainWindow == null)
 {
   return;
 }

 this.MainWindow.Loaded += this.MainWindowOnLoaded;

 this.MainWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
 Debug.Assert(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.MonitorCount > 1);

 Rectangle workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea;
 this.MainWindowLeft = workingArea.Left;
 this.MainWindowTop = workingArea.Top;
 this.MainWindowWidth = workingArea.Width;
 this.MainWindowHeight = workingArea.Height;
 this.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
 this.MainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
 this.MainWindow.Topmost = true;
}

 private void MainWindowOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
 {
   this.MainWindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
 }
```

Comment: Tried System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[__0__]?

Comment: @Rekshino yes, no difference unfortunately...